# Android Beginner Projects

Tags: android, projects

What are some good android beginner projects that can be done? I just bought an android phone and would love to see an app I made on my own phone and show people and potential employers. can I get a list of some good basic projects?

Comment: how about the examples at developer.android.com?

Comment: I've looked over the examples and did most of them. I'm just curious if anyone else had more thoughts on some other projects that could be done.

Comment: In which case, add that information to your original question as it will greatly color the answers you receive (saying 'I just bought' typically means you opened the box and now want to write apps - and so need experience- this is not your situation)

Comment: I think a simple TicTacToe game design would be one of the possible projects to begin learning Android.I am doing the same. GitHun code [here](https://github.com/aniket91/TicTacToe).

Comment: Just curious... what did you end up developing?

Comment: I actually didn't end up developing anything. My focus was switched because of work to wordpress.  :( Looking back....I feel bad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to that is : "Scratch your own itch"

Create an app that solve a problem you would like to be solved.
What could be better in your life and how could your phone help you remove that PITA from your day to day routine.

Then code :D

Good luck.

Comment: Also check out https://developer.android.com/training/index.html  `Here you'll find training classes that describe how to accomplish a specific task with code samples you can re-use in your app.`

Answer (score 3):

budgetDroid...it will keep track of your monthly budget.a very useful project.you can impress your friends,family members and can keep a check on your pocket too !!
but before that you need to study the concepts of Activities,intents and SQlite database.i wold recommend you first visit http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html there are few tutorials on the left hand side fir beginners!

after that read the book 'android for begginers'..which you can download from Internet

Enjoy oFF!
happy programming!!..:)

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. I know there is a mint.com app but I guess I could incorporate my own features and UI.

Answer (score 1):

Try working with the accelerometer and an image of a ball. When the X/Y values of the accelerometer change, move the ball accordingly (e.g., X value positive 9? Move the ball 9 pixels to the right!). That will get you working with a few pieces of the API and, of course, an Activity. You'll also get to learn about screen orientation. :)

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Sounds like it's the beginning to a creation of a game. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Android Developers site at http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html.  They have a large number of tutorials and examples to get you started.  Also, most books related to Android development have an app of some sort that they walk you through, highlighting certain aspects of the OS/device and then implementing them in a coherent program.

Also, the Android SDK includes a number of examples (w/ source code).  I don't have the directory structure in front of me, but I believe the examples for each version of the SDK can be found in their respective directories.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A fun one is a guessing game.  For example have the user try to guess a number between 0 and 100, when they guess have the game tell them if there guess to high or low.  Make sure you randomize the integer so it is different each time.