# need some tutorials and examples, android

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in android, and I need to make a personalized message.
for example if I'm logging in to the app with my username and password, after logging in I need to see the message "welcome username" on the main screen.

In my case I have my contact list and I need pick one name so this one name will be instead of the user name.

I have no idea how to look for it, and I hope I explained myself well for you to understand what I need, can someone guide me to links that has examples of that?

thank you,
Maria

Comment: why don't you try yourself? Its bad to ask others to accomplish your home work without even trying.

Comment: The android website has complete tutorials where you can learn how to develop Android apps. Unless you have a specific question, I'm voting to close.

Comment: I dont even no how to start, what is it relates too, I dont need anyone doing my job, with my poor english (I'm not an american) I cant even write in google what am I looking for, I want to know what topic I need to read and study from

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked a lot of times on SO .

The best site is http://developer.android.com/index.html

1) android tutorials [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579693/android-tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573438/what-are-good-android-books-for-beginners)

2)some good books Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573438/what-are-good-android-books-for-beginners

3) Android Beginner Projects [Android Beginner Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497819/android-beginner-projects)

For Problems with English You can always use
http://itools.com/tool/google-translate-web-page-translator